# Error while installing ghost-phisher tool in kali

Tags: kali-linux

Hello I'm trying to install ghost-phisher tool in kali using github I followed these commands:

Installation

```
 git clone https://github.com/savio-code/ghost-phisher (Download Ghost Phisher)



cd ghost-phisher/Ghost-Phisher

sudo python ghost.py
```

(Run Ghost Phisher) ^^here it says this error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File"ghost.py",line 7,in <module>
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

Update: `cd ghost-phisher && git pull` this should be the last command if the previous worked

```
pip install PyQt4
python -m pip install PyQt4
sudo apt install python-pip
sudo apt update
```

all of them says unable to locate pakage

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/savio-code/ghost-phisher) you need PyQT4 installed and configured as a prerequisite to use ghost-phisher. To get PyQT4 you need to install it [from source](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) or purchase a commercial license. And before you can set up PyQT4, you need to have SIP installed.

Install SIP using `pip install sip`.

[Here is a link](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html) to the documentation on how to install and configure PyQT4.

You need to [download](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) it, unpack it, and check the README for information regarding your platform. As they point out you need to make note of the following:

> Note: When building PyQt4 v4.12.2 or later you must configure SIP to create a private copy of the sip module using a command line similar to the following:
>
> ```
> python configure.py --sip-module PyQt4.sip --no-dist-info --no-tools
> ```

I cannot say what you need to configure specifically because that is dependent on your environment and needs. Please follow the documentation to the letter and refer to River Bank's Computing for support of PyQT4 and the developer of ghost-phisher for support of it respectively.

Best of Luck!